# When sharing a question via email, fill the subject line.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I think the appropriate default email subject should be the question title.

Comment: Looks like this was added in iOS7.  I'm on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will appear in the next build.